# Extension of international internship in France

Tags: research-undergraduate, international-students, internship, policy, france

I am an undergraduate student from India and I was offered a year long research internship in France for my undergraduate thesis. However, since the French government does not allow for internships greater than 6 months my hosts proposed they'll get me another internship for the following 6 months in any of their partner organizations and I could continue my research on the same topic.

But recently I came across this **[blog](https://blog.parisunraveled.com/10-things-you-should-know-about-your-rights-and-responsibilities-as-an-intern-in-france/)** where they mention (the fourth point) that **"students cannot complete more than 6 months of internships for each year they are enrolled in school"**.

Can someone who has been in similar situation or is aware of the french government's internship policies please confirm if this is actually the case and if so does this apply to all students or only students of French universities. And if it is indeed true for all students is there any workaround for this?

Comment: I have indian friends here in Normandie who have been doing "internships" for over a year. I don't know if they are breaking rules to do it but it certainly happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to talk to your advisor and, perhaps the supervisor, also any department that deals with internships.

Believing a blog, written by someone who is not in actual charge of the internships for your institution, is not likely to have the correct information.

Also, if you have had 3 years of a course then that may well mean 3 * 6 months of internships may be possible... But that is detail to discuss with those who know for your position.

Comment: I talked to my supervisor, he ensured me that there won't be any problems what so ever with extension of the internship for another 6 months. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @codetrotter That's good, best wishes.